# XSLT Streaming complex documents

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Most of the examples I see of XSLT 3.0 streaming are fairly simple, and take inputs of the form

```xml
<rootTag>
 <repeatingThing>
   <CDataTag>text</CDataTag> 
   <CDataTag2>text</CDataTag2>
 </repeatingThing>
 <repeatingThing>...</repeatingThing>
</rootTag>
```

Assume you need to touch all the tags inside `repeatingThing`. In this case, streaming works well enough, do a `copy-of` inside your `repeatingThing` template, and you have reduced your memory footprint to 1/X (where X is the number of repeatingThing tags) of its original.

However, I deal with XML that is highly nested. Additionally, because of the nature of my stylesheet (JSON<->XML conversion), I need to touch all the tags in the XML source document. The `copy-of` approach won't work here, as the content is spread over many child nodes, and I'd be copying the entire XML into memory, just more explicitly.

I'm at a loss of how to use streaming to work in this case. A skeleton of such a "hierarchical" document is below:

```xml
<n1:ElectionReport xmlns:n1="NIST_V2_election_results_reporting.xsd">
    <n1:Election>
        <n1:BallotCounts>
            <n1:DeviceClass>
                <n1:Manufacturer/>
                <n1:Model/>
                <n1:Type/>
                <n1:OtherType/>
            </n1:DeviceClass>
            <n1:GpUnitId/>
            <n1:IsSuppressedForPrivacy/>
            <n1:Round/>
            <n1:Type/>
            <n1:OtherType/>
            <n1:BallotsCast/>
            <n1:BallotsOutstanding/>
            <n1:BallotsRejected/>
        </n1:BallotCounts>
        <n1:BallotStyle>
            <n1:ExternalIdentifier>
                <n1:Type/>
                <n1:OtherType/>
                <n1:Value/>
            </n1:ExternalIdentifier>
            <n1:GpUnitIds/>
            <n1:ImageUri/>
            <n1:OrderedContent xsi:type="n1:OrderedContest">
                <n1:ContestId/>
                <n1:OrderedContestSelectionIds/>
            </n1:OrderedContent>
            <n1:PartyIds/>
        </n1:BallotStyle>
        <n1:Candidate ObjectId="">
            <n1:BallotName>
                <n1:Text Language=""/>
            </n1:BallotName>
            <n1:CampaignSlogan>
                <n1:Text Language=""/>
            </n1:CampaignSlogan>
            <n1:ContactInformation>
                <n1:AddressLine/>
                <n1:Directions>
                    <n1:Text Language=""/>
                </n1:Directions>
                <n1:Email/>
                <n1:Fax/>
                <n1:LatLng>
                    <n1:Latitude/>
                    <n1:Longitude/>
                    <n1:Source/>
                </n1:LatLng>
                <n1:Name/>
                <n1:Phone/>
                <n1:Schedule>
                    <n1:Hours>
                        <n1:Day/>
                        <n1:StartTime/>
                        <n1:EndTime/>
                    </n1:Hours>
                    <n1:IsOnlyByAppointment/>
                    <n1:IsOrByAppointment/>
                    <n1:IsSubjectToChange/>
                    <n1:StartDate/>
                    <n1:EndDate/>
                </n1:Schedule>
                <n1:Uri/>
            </n1:ContactInformation>
            <n1:ExternalIdentifier>
                <n1:Type/>
                <n1:OtherType/>
                <n1:Value/>
            </n1:ExternalIdentifier>
            <n1:FileDate/>
            <n1:IsIncumbent/>
            <n1:IsTopTicket/>
            <n1:PartyId/>
            <n1:PersonId/>
            <n1:PostElectionStatus/>
            <n1:PreElectionStatus/>
        </n1:Candidate>
    </n1:Election>
    <n1:SequenceStart/>
    <n1:SequenceEnd/>
    <n1:Status/>
    <n1:TestType/>
    <n1:VendorApplicationId/>
</n1:ElectionReport>
```

Using Saxon-EE 9.8.0.12

Comment: First of all, streaming has its limitations, it is a forwards only, node by node processing. On the other hand, streaming does not depend on the complexity of the document structure, rather on whether you transformation can be achieved using only streamable constructs. Sorting for instance can't be done during streaming. Keys don't work with streaming but some of their uses can be implemented using accumulators. You haven't said what kind of output you want for the shown document and in what way you need to touch all nodes.

Comment: If in order to process the document you need the complete document in memory, and there isn't enough memory, streaming can't help. One could try using accumulators, but this isn't a universal remedy. One can also save the big document into multiple smaller result documents and then try to process these somehow (like with using collection, or loading a document at a time with the document function and using `saxon-discard-document` to repeatedly reuse that memory.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without seeing what output you want to produce. There are some transformations where 100% streaming simply isn't possible (for example, if you want to sort the whole input document), but there are many cases where you can use XSLT 3.0 streaming capabilities to achieve a memory reduction even though there is some buffering involved.

Comment: Some more thoughts: as the namespace declaration seems to refer to a schema and as you seem to want to use streaming which is usually done with the help of Saxon 9 EE I guess you can use schema-aware processing as well. I think that would ease the task of writing templates matching simple types like `xs:double` or `xs:string` with e.g. `<xsl:template match="element(*, xs:double)">` or `<xsl:template match="element(*, xs:string)">` and transforming them to e.g. `<number key="{node-name()}">{.}</number>` or `<string key="{node-name()}">{.}</string>`.

Comment: Without using schema-aware processing you can't decide whether an element has complex or simple content without looking at child nodes and any such "look" means with streaming you need to process the children. On the other hand, the use of schema-aware processing would make part of the streamed processing much easier as that way you basically can check with match patterns whether you process an element with a or derived from a certain simple type so that you can be sure you just map/transform it to its simple JSON representation.

Comment: I have a non-streaming version of the stylesheet complete and working. I just need to figure out how to convert its constructs into streaming equivalents. Because it is a schema-aware transform, it isn't practical to post here. I'll link to a GIST https://gist.github.com/JDziurlaj/60d4f45df0fb7b108a3fdde8803fc330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sample you have linked to is too long to allow me to judge it but at least some templates are written in a style that seems too verbose even if you don't want to use streaming, e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="cdf:LatLng" match="element(*, cdf:LatLng)">
    <xsl:param name="set_type" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:where-populated>
        <string key="Label">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Label"/>
        </string>
    </xsl:where-populated>
    <xsl:where-populated>
        <number key="Latitude">
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Latitude"/>
        </number>
    </xsl:where-populated>
    <xsl:where-populated>
        <number key="Longitude">
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Longitude"/>
        </number>
    </xsl:where-populated>
    <xsl:where-populated>
        <string key="Source">
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Source"/>
        </string>
    </xsl:where-populated>
    <xsl:if test="not($set_type)">
        <string key="@type">ElectionResults.LatLng</string>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

seems to be doable as

```
<xsl:template match="LatLng">
    <xsl:param name="set_type" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="not($set_type)">
        <string key="@type">ElectionResults.LatLng</string>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and then for the child elements and attributes you know that they are simple types you would simply use the approach suggested in my comment e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="element(*, xs:string)">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element(*, xs:double) | element(*, xs:decimal)">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course this basically assumes the child elements are to be processed in the order they are present and you want all of them processed but the last restriction can be eased even with streaming if you use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[self::foo or self::bar]"/>`.

So at least where you simply want to map your known schema types to JSON and have spelled out a lot of different templates for the various elements I think that use of `apply-templates` instead of spelling out various child selections can help to make code streamable. For the types where you have the possible minOccurs=0 and maxOccurs=unbounded I think you can live with

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
  <xsl:variable name="sibling-group" select="copy-of(current-group())"/>
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="tail($sibling-group)">
        <array key="{local-name()}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="$sibling-group"/>
        </array>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$sibling-group"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

instead of the `apply-templates`, that will of course "materialize" the adjacent sibling group of elements of the same name but as you seemed to have spelled out the explicit creation of arrays so far in dedicated templates where you need it you can just rewrite this dedicated templates and don't run the risk of using that approach in general for any element.

If you want to keep the verbose style with the explicit selection of various child elements in the same template then you could try how well Saxon does with the use of `xsl:fork` e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="cdf:LatLng" match="element(*, cdf:LatLng)">
    <xsl:param name="set_type" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:fork>
     <xsl:sequence>
      <xsl:where-populated>
        <string key="Label">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Label"/>
        </string>
      </xsl:where-populated>
     </xsl:sequence>
     <xsl:sequence>
      <xsl:where-populated>
        <number key="Latitude">
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Latitude"/>
        </number>
      </xsl:where-populated>
     </xsl:sequence>
     <xsl:sequence>
      <xsl:where-populated>
        <number key="Longitude">
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Longitude"/>
        </number>
      </xsl:where-populated>
     </xsl:sequence>
     <xsl:sequence>
      <xsl:where-populated>
        <string key="Source">
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Source"/>
        </string>
      </xsl:where-populated>
     </xsl:sequence>
    </xsl:fork>
    <xsl:if test="not($set_type)">
        <string key="@type">ElectionResults.LatLng</string>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The `call-template` use you also have will not be possible with streaming in general. It seems also be used in this stylesheet to process XML elements in a different order than the input order, it seems to output any subelements declared in abstract types after the ones declared in extended types. That of course doesn't work well with the streaming approach of forwards only, node by node processing. So I guess there you have to decide whether you can't output the base subelements first in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks, both these approaches have promise. However, assuming my style sheet follows the sequential order of the input XML in consuming nodes (it could be modified to do so), shouldn't the XSLT engine be able to determine that my stylesheet doesn't violate the rules for streaming (via reading the schema)? Schema uses xs:sequence, no xs:all, so the order is fixed.

Comment: @J.Nicholas, very good question, but as far as I understand https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#notes-on-schema-aware-analysis, at least the theory/spec of streamed processing according to the XSLT 3 standard doesn't take schema information into account. You might want to raise a new, Saxon specific question, as to whether Saxon would additionally support that, i.e. whether "Although such constructs are not guaranteed streamable according to this specification, there is nothing to prevent a processor providing a streamed implementation if it is able to do so" is done in Saxon EE.